# Upgrade 10.04 - 12.04 - How do I upgrade in one step

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 10.04

Unfortunately I have only 1G/mth & have used a lot downloading 12.04. onto a friends W7 - cos I can't get the K3772-Z Vodafone 3G modem to connect - Have got the directions how to get it to work with Ubuntu 12.03 from this site - Many thanks guys 
Should I back-up & install?

Bruce - East London, South Africa

Answer (score 0):

You can't upgrade only with the CD. If you can't connect to the Internet, backup your files and make a new installation.

Well, actually, you can. But that requires good Debian/Ubuntu repository knowledge, and it's far far away from a *one step* procedure.

Maybe your friends W7 can share the connection with an ethernet cable with you, so you can't connect to the Internet? That's not too difficult, but it's out of scope here.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods

**Method-1**


Go to Update manager

->then click on setings

->then a window will pop up "Software sources"

->there u will see " Notify me of a new Ubuntu version: "

 there select "For any new version". Then it will ask for root passwrd for authentication. give it then close it

->Before upgrading you haw to install all the updates for 10.04

->After update close update manager and open it again then you will see a "upgrade" Button for 12.04.

click it

you will have to be connected with internet for this upgrade process.

**Method-2**

Download the new version (12.04 or newer) from the official site
then make some bootable media. **Pendrive** or **CD**
then in installation process
you will find a upgrade option.. then by pressing it the upgrade process will take place. and for this process there will be no requirment of Internet(optional)